# $scope.$apply is not working when inserting data

Tags: angularjs, httprequest

I want to instantly showing new data after http request without reloading the whole page. I found that I can use `$apply` from angularjs for this. But I'm stucked. The data is not showing instantly.

This is the code in controller.

```
$scope.reload = function(data){
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.data = data;
                });
            });
        };
// This part is not working
$scope.addMilestone = function (){

            $http({
                url: httpUrl + 'api/milestone/add',
                method: 'post',
                data: $.param($scope.formData),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
            .then(function (result) {

                $scope.data = result.data;

                $scope.reload($scope.data);

            });
        };
// This part is working
$scope.deleteMilestone = function(id){
            $http.get(httpUrl + 'api/milestone/delete?id=' + rowid).then(function(result){

                if (result.data === 'OK'){                        
                    $http.get(httpUrl + 'api/carts/content').then(function (returns) {
                        $scope.data = returns.data;
                        $scope.reload($scope.data);
                    });

                }
            });
        };
```

What confused me is that this method is working for deleting data, but it's not for inserting new data. In `$scope.deleteMilestone`, the data deleted is removed from the view instantly. I want it also work for `$scope.addMilestone`

Comment: Instead of $scope.reload($scope.data); use $route.reload($scope.data); or simply $route.reload();

Comment: you donot need to relaod the page just `console.log(result.data)` while inserting and check what is coming in it

Comment: @SudhirOjha same result, not working

Comment: @Sravan it returns the correct data so in this case there's no problem with the data, only it's not displayed when I passed it to the view

Comment: `$scope.data = result.data;` This line itself should reload the data if correct data is being sent, just add a console and send that result to answer,

Comment: when I reload the whole page the data newly inserted is there. what I want is it should be displayed right after http request return the results just like what it did in `$scope.deleteMilestone`

Comment: can you console `result` inside then function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166213/discussion-between-sravan-and-abaij).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this for the part  you have written it is not working.

```
$scope.addMilestone = function (){
      $http.post('api/milestone/add', $scope.formData, {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
                         .then(function (result) {

                    $scope.data = result.data;

                    $scope.reload($scope.data);

                });};
```

Comment: `$scope.formData` doesn't seem to pass data to server-side. The value of post data are all `false`

Answer (score 0):

Your delete is working because, you called `get api` after your `delete`, but for `add` you didnt make that API call, **so data isnt being reloaded for you**.

Change your add milestone method to,

```
$scope.addMilestone = function (){
    $http({
        url: httpUrl + 'api/milestone/add',
        method: 'post',
        data: $.param($scope.formData),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        if (result){                        
            $http.get(httpUrl + 'api/carts/content').then(function (returns) {
                $scope.data = returns.data;
                $scope.reload($scope.data);
            });

        }

    });
};
```

Comment: still no luck. I did `console.log(returns.data)` inside the function and it return the data correctly